# Cannot access s3 from application running on EKS EC2 instance, IAM assume role permissions issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, airflow, amazon-iam

*NOTE: similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38449069/aws-assume-role-with-ec2-instance-iam-role-not-working), but no proper solution provided.*

I setted up an EKS cluster via eksctl tool with single EC2 node. Deploy a Pod inside the EC2 node, this Pod writes the logs into s3 bucket. All worked fine when I used IAM user with key and secret. But now I want this Pod to use IAM Role instead. This Pod uses a newly created role with `AmazonS3FullAccess` permissions named `prod-airflow-logs`. According to the [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html), I also added `"ec2.amazonaws.com"` in this role's trust Relationship as follows;

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "s3.amazonaws.com",
          "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

EC2 Node has its own Role named `eksctl-prod-eks-nod-NodeInstanceRole-D4JQ2Q6D9GDA`. If I understand correct, this role has to assume role `prod-airflow-logs` in order to allow container Pod to access and store logs in s3. According to the same [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html), I attached an in-line policy in this Node Role as follows;

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "ec2:*",
                "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I still get following error in kubernetes pod when it tried to store logs on s3;

**botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXX:assumed-role/eksctl-prod-eks-nod-NodeInstanceRole-D4JQ2Q6D9GDA/i-0254e5b5b36e58f79 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/prod-airflow-logs**

The only thing I don't understand from this error is, which user is it referring to ?
Where on earth is this user `User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXX:assumed-role/eksctl-prod-eks-nod-NodeInstanceRole-D4JQ2Q6D9GDA/i-0254e5b5b36e58f79` ? Would appreciate if someone could point out what exactly I am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

No answer yet... Here is how I made this work, I had to add the arn of Node Role into the trust policy of Pod Execution role. 
In my case, the Pod execution role is `prod-airflow-logs` and the Node Role is `eksctl-prod-eks-nod-NodeInstanceRole-D4JQ2Q6D9GDA`.

The trust relationship of Pod execution has to be as follows;

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:role/eksctl-prod-eks-nod-NodeInstanceRole-D4JQ2Q6D9GDA"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```